# Non-constant function such that $\int_{\partial B_1(0)} \omega f(\omega r) d\omega = 0$ for every $r \ge 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

What are examples of a function $f:\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R$, other than constant functions, such that $$\int_{\partial B_1(0)} \omega f(\omega r) d\omega = 0$$ for every $r \ge 0$, where $\partial B_1(0)$ denotes the sphere of unit radius around the origin?

Comment: What is $\partial B_1(0)$?

Comment: @AdamZalcman The boundary of the ball of radius 1 and center 0

Comment: Are constant functions trivial?

Comment: @UmbertoP. yes, no constant examples

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @UmbertoP. I couldn't find anything. Except, in fact, constants. Maybe a radial function works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function with [*even symmetry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Multivariate_functions), i.e. $f$ such that

$$
f(\omega) = f(-\omega)\tag1
$$

makes the integral vanish. A few concrete examples are

$$
f(x_1, \dots, x_N) = c \\
f(x_1, \dots, x_N) = x_i^2 \\
f(x_1, \dots, x_N) = \cos(x_i) \\
f(x_1, \dots, x_N) = \exp\left(x_i^2\right) \\
f(x_1, \dots, x_N) = \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^N x_k^2\right)
$$

where $i\in\{1, \dots, N\}$. If $N$ is even then another example is

$$
f(x_1, \dots, x_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N x_i\tag2.
$$

Comment: Can you give an example where the function depends on all the coordinates instead of just the i-th?. Also what is a function with antipodal symmetry?

Comment: Antipodal symmetry is just a term I gave to functions with property $(1)$ which serves as the definition. An example of a suitable function that depends on all coordinates in case $N$ is even is given by $(2)$. If $N$ is odd, you can still use $(2)$, but one of the coordinates needs to be raised to an even power.

Comment: What about radial functions?

Comment: Added a radial example (the Gaussian).

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally, what about a compactly supported example? Is it possible? And, by the way, is it true that the assumption in the question implies $\nabla f(0) = 0$?

Comment: Sure, a compactly supported example is provided by any of the examples given, except that you define $f$ to be $0$ outside the disk of some radius, like 1.

Comment: Thank you! What about $\nabla f(0) = 0$? Is it implied by the condition $\int_{\partial B_1} \omega f(\omega r) = 0$?

Comment: Yes. The vanishing of the integral for every $r\ge 0$ implies the vanishing of the gradient at the origin. See the [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) or [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem) for more general approach.